# is sheet.getRange(2:3) a valid expression?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on google sheets using google apps script. I want to iterate over a bunch of rows - conditionally select a few of them - and delete the selected ones. I'm using the sheet.getRange() method to achieve this. I want to pass my iterating variable directly to the function. But isn't working.

I found the below sample code in (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/group) Group class using getRange() method itself.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange(2:3);
range.shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
var group = sheet.getRowGroupAt(2, 1);
//Expands this group.
group.expand();
```

Here is my code

```
var data = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

for (var k = 1; k<=data.length;k++){

    if((data[k]-data[k-1]) == 0)
    {
        sheet.getRange(k:k).activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: See the [various options for .getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) where you can use a Row and Column number and optional counts or A1 notation.

Comment: I will not be able to iterate using any other notation. Is the sample code given in google guides in wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not valid. Google made a mistake. It should be quoted to be valid JavaScript:

```
var range = sheet.getRange('2:3');
```

Or

```
sheet.getRange(k + ':' + k).activate();
```

Answer (score 1):

data[k] doesn't have a numeric value as you'e written it. to access the individual items in data you need to do data[k][0]. I'd try logging that value to make sure it says what you are expecting. Your other road block is that activate isn't deleting. The final problem you have is that you are going up rather than down so you'll skip rows if you delete some of them (so you need to iterate from the end to the beginning). Does this work for you?

```
var data = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

for (var k = data.length-1; k>0;k--){

    if((data[k][0]-data[k-1][0]) == 0)
    {
        sheet.deleteRow(k+1);//array addresses are off by 1 because rows count from 1 and arrays count from 0
    }
}
```